# Inner class member variables do not get assigned properly

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

I have two classes

1. **OTPBroadcastReceiver** - a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` and extracts a one-time-password (OTP henceforth) from the newly arrived SMS.
2. **OTPListener** - a class that actually initiates the previous class with a ***callback*** in it that is supposed to get executed when the SMS is received and OTP is extracted.

The callback has a method `onOTPReceived(long timeReceived, final String otp)` that gets executed by the OTPBroadcastReceiver & it passes it the time the message arrived as `long` and the OTP message as `String`.

I have an **inner-class** in my OTPListener that has the following member variables: -

```
 private class OTPModel {

        long timeReceived = 0L;
        String otp = null;
    }
```

This class is used to store the OTP message and the time the message was received.

Following is the code for **OTPListener**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

class OTPListener {

    private OTPReceivedInternal mOTPReceivedCallback;
    private OTPModel mOTPModel;


    OTPListener(@NonNull final Context context,
                final List<SMSRule> smsRules,
                @NonNull final CustomOTPView.OnOTPReceivedCallback onOTPReceivedCallback) {

        mOTPModel = new OTPModel();

        mOTPReceivedCallback = new OTPReceivedInternal() {

            @Override
            public void onOTPReceived(long timeReceived, String otp) {

                if (mOTPModel.timeReceived == 0L) {

                    mOTPModel.timeReceived = timeReceived;
                    mOTPModel.otp = otp;
                    onOTPReceivedCallback.onOTPReceived(mOTPModel.otp);
                    System.out.println("First execution");
                    System.out.println("Value of mOTPModel.otp:" + mOTPModel.otp);
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(mOTPModel.timeReceived));
                } else {

                    if (!mOTPModel.otp.equals(otp)) {
                        if (timeReceived > mOTPModel.timeReceived) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(timeReceived > mOTPModel.timeReceived),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mOTPModel.timeReceived = timeReceived;
                            onOTPReceivedCallback.onOTPReceived(mOTPModel.otp = otp);
                            System.out.println("After first execution");
                            System.out.println("{{Value of mOTPModel.timeReceived:" + String.valueOf(mOTPModel.timeReceived));
                            System.out.println("Value of mOTPModel.otp:" + String.valueOf(mOTPModel.otp)+"}}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };


        new OTPBroadcastReceiver(context,smsRules,mOTPReceivedCallback);
    }

    private class OTPModel {

        long timeReceived = 0L;
        String otp = null;
    }

    protected interface OTPReceivedInternal {

        void onOTPReceived(long timeReceived, String otp);

    }
```

**Problem here is**,

the **1st time** it executes, the

`mOTPModel.timeReceived` & `mOTPModel.otp`

are both null even after the following assignment statements

```
mOTPModel.timeReceived = timeReceived;
mOTPModel.otp = otp;
```

And the only thing that gets printed on my Android Monitor is

```
System.out.println("First execution");
```

The next two statements following it immediately don't even execute.

The **2nd time** it executes, the `else` part of the code gets executed, but this time it prints the old values of `mOTPModel.otp` and `mOTPModel.timeReceived` and the subsequent executions keep displaying the previous values.

What is going wrong here? Why aren't the member variables of the **OTPModel** class getting assigned properly?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hint: read about "single layer of abstraction" principle. Having the code for your callback inside your constructor really doesn't help at all with readability! And from a design point of view: it seems that "OTPModel" is an essential part of your design; so I am wondering if it should really be an private inner class; and not something that deserves to be a "first class citizen".

Comment: Then: you say that "First execution" is printed; but what about the following two printlns in that block. What do they print?! And: pay attention to your wording: *timeReceived* is an *long*, it cant be **null** therefore. Only objects references can be null! long are maybe 0, but not null!

Comment: I will definitely look up the "single layer of abstraction" & I will move out the callback code from my constructor as well. But could you please elaborate on what you mean by OTPModel not deserving a "first class citizen"?

Comment: I mean: I would make OTPModel its own public class. And I would call it OneTimePassword instead; make the fields private, maybe even final; and for example: implement equals() so that you dont need to compare objects of this class ... by **externally** comparing its fields. Ask the OTP objects to decide if it is equal to another one.

Comment: @GhostCat After the `First execution`, the next two statements **don't print** AT ALL. It is only in the next execution that they print the older values. And my `timeReceived` is long and as far as I understand, `long` is a primitive type and it has a default value of `0L`. Besides, in y object creation itself the member variables are assigned 0L and null.

Comment: Strange. Normally the stream should flush after println(), but maybe Android is handling stuff differently. So, you could try to call flush() after each println to see if that changes anything.

Comment: How about printing all that logging in a single println() call?

Comment: My current thinking goes into the same direction; but more like: you are sure that the code you are showing here is really the same that gets executed. So, my next experiment would be: A) just change the message for the statement that gets printed. B) If "A)" worked, then try pulling all messages into a single println call.

Comment: I tried and it is now printing all the messages in a single line. I'm getting the value of `timeReceived` as 0L and that of `otp` as null in the first run and the older values in the second run, which means the problem is still there

Comment: Funny thing is, I simulated the same thing on Eclipse IDE (except for the BroadcastReceiver thing) and it was giving me the expected output. I have no clue what in the world is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cause of your problems lies outside the scope of the code you have shown. Where is the listener instantiated? Are multiple instances of it created?

How did you determine that `otp` and `timeReceived` are null after their assignments? Maybe it's an idea to check the incoming values of `otp` and `timeReceived` too (either by debugging or with some more logging statements).

The fact that some `System.out.println` is not seen must be either a problem with your logging or some debugging/threading issue that stops the process.

Further comments:

```
private OTPReceivedInternal mOTPReceivedCallback;
```

Confusing field name, I'd rename it to `otpReceivedInternal`. Especially since there is also a constructor parameter named `onOTPReceivedCallback`.

```
onOTPReceivedCallback.onOTPReceived(mOTPModel.otp = otp);
```

Confusing idiom. I'd split it into:

```
mOTPModel.otp = otp;
onOTPReceivedCallback.onOTPReceived(otp);
```

This is much more readable.

EDIT: so this is the change I am now suggesting to find out what's happening

```
        @Override
        public void onOTPReceived(long timeReceived, String otp) {

 // print the received values
 System.out.printf("timeReceived = %s, otp = %s", timeReceived, otp);

            if (mOTPModel.timeReceived == 0L) {

                mOTPModel.timeReceived = timeReceived;
                mOTPModel.otp = otp;
                onOTPReceivedCallback.onOTPReceived(mOTPModel.otp);

 // print the mOTPModel values
 System.out.printf("1: mOTPModel.timeReceived = %s, mOTPModel.otp= %s", mOTPModel.timeReceived, mOTPModel.otp);
 System.out.flush();

                // ... carry on
```

Comment: When I ran my app in debug mode, in the first execution itself the values for `otp` and `timeReceived` **of the OTPModel class** turned out to be null despite the two assignment statements that precede them.

Comment: I'm running only one instance of the **OTPBroadcastReceiver** and in this class the OTP is being extracted as a `String` and the time it arrived as `long`. There is no issue on the OTPBroadcastReceiver class. It's only in the OTPListener acting strange

Comment: Alright!! I will make the changes required for making it more readable, but that wouldn't help the case, would it?

Comment: Those changes will indeed not solve the problem - they were under 'further remarks' regarding style/readability. As pointed out by others: `OTPModel.timeReceived` cannot possibly ever be null. It's a primitive (long) so it always has a value. So how exactly did you come tot the conclusion that it was null?

Comment: My Bad!! `OTPModel.timeReceived` never showed null, rather `0L` in debug mode. But the print statement containing it never got executed, which is what puzzles me. Even if it doesn't get any value assigned to it, it should at least print the `0L`, the defined value, right?

Comment: So try to combine the print statements into one, and flush System,out afterwards just to be sure (suggestion from @GhostCat). And also print the received values of the method right after entry. I'm guessing you are receiving 0L and null values the first time round...

Comment: The variables, whose values are to be assigned, contain the expected values, that are some `1476734...` for `timeReceived` and some `898392` for`otp`. But after the assignment, when I try to print the variables to the which the values have just been assigned, I get the older values.

Comment: The only thing I can come up with is that there must be some multi-threading issue going on. Seeing values disappear after assignment can't really be explained any other way. Either that, or your tooling is fooling you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: check the values that `onOTPReceived(long timeReceived, String otp)` itself receives.

It wouldn't surprise me if that method is invoked with (0, null); thus your OTPMOdel object ... starts with initial values(0, null) ... to be "updated" to (0, null) afterwards.

Comment: I checked. It returns the expected values, that is a `long` value and a `String` value (**no Null and no 0**). But would you say my program is logically correct? And if yes, then why this problem? Could this be an internal issue of Android Studio?

Comment: For the moment; I am running out of ideas. This is really strange. I guess I would need to sit in front of your system to figure what to do next.